Optimization of eigenvalue of matrix with discrete variables

Suppose we have a matrix $H$ like this, where $H_{ii}$ is a discrete variable (for example out of $[1,2,3]$) and $H_{ij}$ is a value that depends on the two adjacent values ($H_{ii}$ and $H_{jj}$). $H$ is symmetric, i.e., $H_{ij} = H_{ji}$.
Formally:


Would it be possible to optimize the $H_{ii}$s along the diagonal, so that the eigenvalues of the matrix fulfil some property? For example, maximizing the sum of all eigenvalues, or the gap between the $N/2$ and $N/2+1$ eigenvalue?
PS: for those interested, the types or discrete variables for $H_{ii}$ correspond to atom types in a molecule and $H_{ij}$ specifies a bond characteristic between atom $i$ and $j.$
Edit: I already solved this by first calculating the characteristic polynomial and then using MINLP. The problem is that the expression explodes for large matrices and makes it infeasible to solve, so I am trying to find a way to use the matrix directly.

[NOT an answer] It likely would depend on the specific property. Are you free to set the $H_{ii}$s as you wish but then $H_{ij}$ is a function of $H_{ii}$ and $H_{jj}$? THANK YOU for putting in context and for motivating this.

Yes exactly, we can choose the $H_{ii}s$ freely, and the $H_{ij}$ is just a certain value, depending on the combination. For example, if $H_{11} = 1$ (e.g. Carbon) and $H_{22} = 2$ (Nitrogen or so), then $H_{12} = H_{21}$ would be a value specific to the carbon nitrogen bond.
